# Making the Timer Elapsed Event Sleep

Tags: c#, timer

i am using a timer elapsed event for automatic database backup, the timer will check for every 5 seconds, once the current time equals to the time given in app.config the database backup will happen. I want to make the timer not to check again immediately when the backup happen. can anyone help me this.

Comment: Do you refer to the System.Windows.Forms.Timer, the System.Timers.Timer, or the System.Threading.Timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once the current time equals to the time given in app.config the database backup will happen

That has a knack of not working.  The config could say 10:05:00, the timer elapses at 10:04:58 and 10:05:03.  There's no point in firing that timer every 5 seconds.  Just fire it once.  When the backup is due.  If the user changes the due time, stop and re-start the timer to use the altered TimeSpan.

Answer (score 1):

If using the Sytem.Timers.Timer object you would do

```
timer.Stop()
```

as the first line in your elapsed event, then do the backup, and do

```
timer.Start()
```

at the end to restart the event.

If using System.Threading.Timer use

```
timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)
```

and then restart it with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

Pause the timer when the backup is running.

Otherwise.. (Not sure what DBS you are using) why not use SQL Server Agent Jobs?